# Proper way to implement python-social-auth with Django and Steam backend

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, steam

I want to use [Python Social Auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/) to authenticate my users using the Steam OpenId back end. I've followed the Django Configuration [steps](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html). But, at this point I don't know the next steps.

Theoretically, my application is ready to use the OpenId provider but I can't find anything in the documentation that tells me *how* to use the provider. What do I need to do to make use of this functionality?

Answer (score 6):

Probably a bit late for a useful answer, but just in case... this is a bare bones procedure I just cobbled together, but should get you started. Assuming you got the Django-specific parts done (including `syncdb`), what you need now is to complete the generic Social Auth and Steam configuration...

You need a Steam API key (get it [here](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/))

In `settings.py`, add the key:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_STEAM_API_KEY = '...'
```

And add the backend:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.steam.SteamOpenId',
    #others, if you want them...
)
```

In `urls.py`, add the social URLs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
)
```

Now create your login link using `/login/steam?next=/`, where `next` is where the user should land post-login. For the login link, make sure you follow the guidance on the Steam dev community page and use an appropriate image. And note that the default pipeline will auto-create the Django user.

Like I said, bare bones (I didn't do anything with the template context processors), but hopefully it helps.